# Spring Security ignores failed authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm in the process of setting up Spring Security. My `CookieAuthenticationFilter` should make sure to keep users out unless they have a cookie with an UUID we accept. Although `CookieAuthenticationFilter` sets an empty context if the UUID is not accepted I still have access to all URLs.

Any idea what's missing?

This is my security configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class LIRSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilter(cookieAuthenticationFilter())
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyAuthority("ALL");
    }

    @Bean
    public CookieAuthenticationFilter cookieAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new CookieAuthenticationFilter(cookieService());
    }

    private CookieService cookieService() {
        return new CookieService.Impl();
    }

    @Bean(name = "springSecurityFilterChain")
    public FilterChainProxy getFilterChainProxy() {
        SecurityFilterChain chain = new SecurityFilterChain() {

            @Override
            public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                // All goes through here
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public List<Filter> getFilters() {
                List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<Filter>();
                filters.add(cookieAuthenticationFilter());
                return filters;
            }
        };
        return new FilterChainProxy(chain);
    }

}
```

This is the `CookieAuthenticationFilter` implementation:

```
public class CookieAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Resource
    protected AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    private CookieService cookieService;

    public CookieAuthenticationFilter(CookieService cookieService) {
        super();
        this.cookieService = cookieService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        UUID uuid = cookieService.extractUUID(request.getCookies());

        UserInfo userInfo = authenticationService.findBySessionKey(uuid);
        SecurityContext securityContext = null;
        if (userInfo != null) {
            securityContext = new CookieSecurityContext(userInfo);
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        } else {
            securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        }

        try {
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        finally {
            // Free the thread of the context
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't want to use `GenericFilterBean` as it's not actually part of the Spring Security framework, just regular Spring so it's not aware of how to send security-related messages back to the browser or deny access, etc.  If you do want to use the `GenericFilterBean` you'll need to handle the redirect or the 401 response yourself.  Alternatively, look into the `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` that is part of the Spring Security framework.  There is some documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html

Comment: I do understand how to implement a `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` for my need. But I'm stuck beyond this. My filter will read the principal from the request. Where am I supposed to process the principal. There must be a place where I tell the security system *this is a valid principle for user foo*. Any ideas where this functionality should go?

Comment: @BetaRide the way that I've done it in the past is to have the filter throw an `UnknownUsernameException` if the authentication fails.  That may not be the _correct_ way to do it so somebody else, please feel free to chime in, but I've had success with that approach in the past.